# selecting drop-down option of variable which contain html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A variable contains html

```
var empDaysStatusDropDown =
"<select class='statusList form-control'><option value='1'>Official On</option><option value='2'>Official Off</option><option value='3'>Sick Leave</option><option value='4'>Casual Leave</option><option value='5'>Annual Leave</option></select>"
```

I want to update this html through programming by selecting any of the dropdown option?

Means I want to select any of the option either 0,1,2,3 of dropdown and update html accordingly so that as I show that html on page the option will see  selected which i select first

Comment: Append the HTML and then use `val()` to set the selected option. To do what you suggest (amending the string to add the 'selected' attribute manually) will get complicated and is a bit hacky.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

I have also created the fiddle for it : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0Lfppktc/1/)

According to me you need to implement it before appending it to the page. So you want to manipulate it in jquery, Here we go:

```
var empDaysStatusDropDown =
$("<select class='statusList form-control'><option value='1'>Official On</option><option value='2'>Official Off</option><option value='3'>Sick Leave</option><option value='4'>Casual Leave</option><option value='5'>Annual Leave</option></select>");
empDaysStatusDropDown.find('option[value="1"]').attr('selected','selected');
// now you can append empDaysDropDown anywhere on the page.
$('body').append(empDaysStatusDropDown);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: You are trying to alert it ?

Comment: yeah it showing [object Object]. when i am directly this varaible appending the show correctly but i want to show dont like this

Comment: Why do you need to alert it ? just use it and append it on the page like in my fiddle.

Comment: i cant directly append it. I am doing like this

Comment: var empDaysStatusDD = $jqueryLib(empDaysStatusDropDown);
                        empDaysStatusDD.find('option[value="2"]').attr('selected','selected');  html += "<tr class='empDaysAdd' id='empStatusId_"+ empStatusData[i].empSwitchId+"'><td>" +
                        i + '. ' + empStatusData[i].Employee_Name + "</td><td>" +
                        empStatusData[i].projectName + "</td><td id =ab" + empStatusData[i].empSwitchId + ">"+
                        empDaysStatusDropDown + "</td></tr>";  $jqueryLib("#displayEmpDayStatus").html(html);

Comment: remove jqueryLib, Just make it $(empDaysStatusDropDown)

Comment: thats not a problem it use due to jquery conflict

Comment: create a fiddle for the same

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this
$(document.body).on("change",".statusList",function(){
  if(".statusList option:selected").val()=="1"){
   empDaysStatusDropDown ="new html";
  }
})
```

Comment: Please explain your answer not just paste code here